# Why the aopalliance package is imported for android project?

Tags: android, aop, ioc-container

I am working on a project which uses *Android Studio* as the IDE, and *google guice* as the IoC container.

I added the *guice* dependency like this:

```
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0:no_aop'
```

in the **build.gradle** file. But after I refreshed the project, I still have the **aopalliance** library imported into my project.

How can I remove the *aop* dependency? Since it cannot be used in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer to this. But one simple solution is: if you are concerned about the app size, use **proguard** to remove it from the compiled code.